# Specifying z-order (sendSubviewToBack, etc.) on UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uistackview, z-order

According to the Apple docs:

> The order of the subviews array defines the Z-order of the subviews. If the views overlap, subviews with a lower index appear behind subviews with a higher index.

I can see that this is the case, as I am trying to have its arrangedSubviews manually reordered using `sendSubviewToBack`, which is having no effect. How can I adjust the z-order of the arrangedSubviews in a UIStackView?

Comment: See the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/43714481/2924596

Answer (score 11):

Use this!

`yourArrangedSubview.layer.zPosition = xxx`

Comment: This seems to work, but it seems to be undocumented behavior. On which iOS versions will work? will it break in the future? I wouldn't rely on this except for cosmetic changes that you are OK might break at some point.

Comment: Hard to say. I wrote this answer several years ago. Seems to still be working nicely. 

I would imagine as long as UIStackView and UIView don't change too dramatically, this should work.